# Bootstrap module with component from external module

Tags: angular, typescript

**Edit on 11-4-2017**

Figured out that what I'm trying to do is possible (as can be seen with the code from [this repository](https://github.com/kajnelissen/so-custom-sample)). So apparently something else is causing the issue. When I run the standard application on its own, it compiles fine. So what could be the cause of its main component not able to being resolved after I package it?

**-----**

So we're building an application using Angular (v4.x). It receives some payload from the server that contains a definition of the controls present on the page, parses that payload and then creates all these controls. Some examples of controls are a textbox and a dropdown list. The controls are implemented as components, so we have a `TextboxComponent` and a `DropdownListComponent` for example.

The idea is that we build a standard version of the application. Customers should be able to customize that standard version and create their own customized application with additional controls. They might define and implement a `ZipcodeComponent` for example. I did the following things in order to be able to achieve this:

- I created a npm package of the standard application using `npm pack`. Let's call this the standard package.
- I created a new Angular application.
- I installed the standard package as a dependency for the new application with `npm install`.

I thought I would now be able to use the bootstrap component from the standard package as the bootstrap component for the custom application. However, I receive the following error message when trying to build the custom application:

```
Error in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'standard-app' in 'Some\Path\src' @ ./src/main.ts 5:23-48
```

The `main.ts` from the **standard** application looks like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The `main.ts` file from the **custom** application looks like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomAppModule } from './app/customapp.module';

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CustomAppModule);
```

The `app.module.ts` of the **standard** application looks like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [ /* some imports */ ],
    entryComponents: [
        MainComponent,
        // other components
    ],
    declarations: [
        MainComponent, AppComponent, LoginComponent,
        // other components
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ /* some providers */ ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, the `customapp.module.ts` from the **custom** application:

```
import { AppModule as StandardAppModule } from 'standard-app';
import { AppComponent as StandardAppBootstrapComponent } from 'standard-app';
import { CustomAppComponent } from "./customapp.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [ StandardAppModule ],
    entryComponents: [],
    declarations: [ CustomAppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ StandardAppBootstrapComponent ],
    providers: []
})
export class CustomModule { }
```

I have a feeling that I'm missing something trivial here, but I have no clue what it would be. Note the `bootstrap` entry in the `customapp.module.ts` file where the bootstrap component from the standard application is used. Might anyone be able to explain to me what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!